# ASP.Net MVC Website.. extremely slow after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi
I've been working on a medium sized MVC project. It works fine on the localhost at a good speed rate. In each page, there's a lot of server-side data retrieved, I use a lot of jquery to minimize the traffic to the server, but even then, the webpage loads very slowly. There are many events on which I retrieve json results, to get a specific number from the database and make calculations, this data takes a long time to be retrieved on the webpage, although on the localhost it is immediately shown. Also, when I submit pages, it takes awfully a lot of time to submit.  I've published my project to GoDaddy's server and also my database is there. What could be the problem that is making the project that slow? How can I minimize it? And why is it only when the website is online and not on the localhost too?

Answer (score 0):

As such, issue can be anywhere and only certain way to know is instrumenting the code. I will suggest that you add simple logging traces with date-time stamp in your server code (note that logging should be configurable, any logging framework (including System.Diagnostic.Trace) should support it) and check where the time is spent. For example, database trips can be expensive etc. If you don't find the culprit on server side code i.e. sever is serving the request in reasonable time then you have to look at the performance over network. Tools such as Fiddler (or Firefox) should help you here - sometimes issuing too many requests from browser is also problematic because browser may make only n concurrent requests or even server may have been configured to accept only n requests from particular client - this could result in serialization of request increasing total response time. These scenarios are difficult to catch on localhost because network latency is almost zero there. You may also use tool such as [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for related performance improvement suggestions. But please do your investigation first, find the bottlenecks and then ask for solutions to specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in chrome. Turn on the developer tools. Expand the Console. watch for errors. Also from there you can monitor those network calls to see which is slow.

Answer (score -2):

if MVC uses entity framework (based on LINQ), it will sure be slow
because LINQ is slow compared to the old ADO.NET

Comment: "*LINQ is slow compared to the old ADO.NET*" - is it?

Comment: kamal101 - Based on what evidence have you made this statement ?